# MYSQL select from table where field is in the field

Tags: mysql, sql

UPDATED

```
id  |  id_list
1   |  2,3,5,7
2   |  1,4,5,6
3   |  1,4,6,7
4   |  2,3,5,8
5   |  1,2,4,8
6   |  2,3,7,8
7   |  1,3,6,9
8   |  4,5,6,9
9   |  7,8
```

let's say I'm up to the content of id=1

I wanted to select all the rows where id is in id_list of id=1 PLUS the row where id=1

so the result would be
rows with id = 1,2,3,5,7

How to do this query guys?

Comment: who create this database ? you don't you use one to many relation ? and I didn't catch you question.

Comment: I made it by myself. I don't get what you mean "one to many relation "

Comment: why is the result `id = 1,5,3,6,8`?

Comment: are  these ids is related to other ids ? such as products gifts ?

Comment: @ivory-santos Is this question actually answered?

Comment: @ivory-santos which error are you still facing?

Comment: I used Kyle answer but the row return is only in the first condition, the other don't. here is kyle anser. SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE id = '1'
OR id IN ('\''+(SELECT REPLACE(id_list,',','\',\'') FROM your_table WHERE id = '1')+'\'')

Comment: @ivory-santos i guess i misunderstood the question, did you check my answer below? isnt this the result you need? you wrote "the result would be rows with id = 1,2,3,5,7"?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a self join

Using `IN()`

```
select * from atable a
join atable b on (a.id = b.id )
where 1 IN (a.id_list) or   b.id =1
```

[**Fiddle with IN()**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17a6e/9)

Using `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
select * from atable a
join atable b on (a.id = b.id )
where FIND_IN_SET('1', a.id_list) or   b.id =1
```

[**Fiddle with FIND_IN_SET()**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17a6e/11)

Using `UNION ALL`

```
select * from atable 
where id =1
UNION ALL 
select * from atable 
where 1 IN (id_list)
```

[**Fiddle with UNION ALL**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17a6e/13)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f8a4/25)):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE id = 1
OR INSTR((SELECT id_list FROM tbl WHERE id = '1'), id) > 0;
```

*Tested with MySQL 5.5.30*

Answer (score 0):

Your database design is broken; `id_list` should be represented as a join table instead of as a string. However, to solve your immediate problem:

```
select * from table where id=1 
          or id_list like '1%' 
          or id_list like '%,1,%'
          or id_list like '%,1'
```

Adjust as needed for `PreparedStatement`.  You have to provide all three cases because if you just did

```
  or id_list like '%1%'
```

and `id_list` contained the value `11`, you'd get an incorrect match

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select * 
from tbl 
where id=1 
or id_list like '%1%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to call for a union of two sets. The one set would be the single row whose `id` matches the specified value:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  atable
WHERE
  id = @id
```

The other set would be the result of this self-join:

```
SELECT
  item.id
FROM
  atable AS item
INNER JOIN
  atable AS list
ON
  FIND_IN_SET(item.id, list.id_list)
WHERE
  list.id = @id
```

That is, the row with the specified `id` is matched against every row in the table on the condition that the other row's `id` is found in the specified row's `id_list`.

You can try the complete query [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17a6e/3).

Please note that lists aren't a very good design feature. In your situation, it might be better to use a many-to-many table as [suggested by @Othman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196283/297408). Only I would probably use a slightly different query to get the desired output, because his doesn't include the specified row itself:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  manytomany
WHERE
  id = @id

UNION

SELECT
  linked_id
FROM
  manytomany
WHERE
  id = @id
;
```

While the entries in `manytomany` are assumed to be unique, the query uses the UNION DISTINCT operator because of the potential duplicates returned by the first subquery, although it is possible to move the application of DISTINCT to the first subquery only like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  id
FROM
  manytomany
WHERE
  id = @id

UNION ALL

SELECT
  linked_id
FROM
  manytomany
WHERE
  id = @id
;
```

That first subquery could actually be rewritten simply as `SELECT @id AS id`, but the rewrite would only make sense if the passed value was guaranteed to be valid, i.e. that it would definitely be found in `manytomany.id`.

[Here's a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1d7a/8) for the other approach too (all three variations, including the `SELECT @id AS id` one).

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are using php..

My suggestion is to grab the id_list for id 1. 

Explode that id_list on the comma, and then do another mysql query to grab the remaining results for 5|3|6|8

ex) $idarray = explode(",", $result);

select * from your_table where id in ('5','3','6','8')

OPTION 2:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE id = '1'
OR id IN ('\''+(SELECT REPLACE(id_list,',','\',\'') FROM your_table WHERE id = '1')+'\'')
```

EDIT: Oops, sorry, that should be an OR instead.

Comment: yup that is one of my option. But I am trying to make it in a single query. Thanks by the way.

Comment: This may be syntactically wrong, most likely the escape characters. I didn't run it against MySQL, but this may help...EDIT: apparently I can't format in my comment, so i posted it my main post :p

Comment: only the first condition is satisfied, the other rows don't show

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an answer for your question but I encourage you to redesign your table like this I think this called many to many relation

```
id  |  friend
1   |    2
1   |    3
1   |    5
1   |    7
2   |    1
2   |    4
2   |    5
2   |    6
3   |    1
3   |    4
3   |    6
3   |    7
```

And then your query will be like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(friend) FROM `new` WHERE id = 1
```